# How to test api call in react component and expect the view change after success of api call?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a simple react component with only one button, when that button is clicked it makes a api call using fetch, after the success call is calls setState to update the component.

in my my-button.jsx file

```
import React from "react";

export default class MyButton extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            user: null
        }
        this.getUser = this.getUser.bind(this);
    }

    async getUser() {
        try {
            const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/users");
            if (res.status >= 400)
                throw new Error("something went wrong");

            const user = await res.json();
            this.setState({ user });

        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
        }


    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.getUser}>Click Me</button>
                {this.state.user ? <p>got user</p> : null}
            </div>
        )
    }


}
```

in my test file

```
import React from "react";
import { shallow, Mount } from "enzyme";
import MyButton from "../my-button";


beforeAll(() => {
    global.fetch = jest.fn();
});

it("must test the button click", (done) => {

    fetch.mockImplementation(() => {
        return Promise.resolve({
            status: 200,
            json: () => {
                return Promise.resolve({ name: "Manas", userId: 2 });
            }
        });
    });
    const wrapper = shallow(<MyButton />);


    wrapper.find("button").simulate("click");

    //here using setTimeout to delay the find call, How to avoid using setTimeout
    setTimeout(() => {
        wrapper.update();
        expect(wrapper.find("p").length).toBe(1);
        fetch.mockClear();
        done();
    }, 1000)
})
```

I am using setTime out to delay the expect call how to avoid using setTimeout as it is not the efficient way to test.

my test fails if i don't use setTimeout

```
 src/App.test.js
 FAIL  src/components/__test__/my-button.test.js
  ● must test the button click

    expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: 1
    Received: 0

      26 |     // setTimeout(() => {
      27 |     wrapper.update();
    > 28 |     expect(wrapper.find("p").length).toBe(1);
         |                                      ^
      29 |     fetch.mockClear();
      30 |     done();
      31 |     // }, 1000)

      at Object.toBe (src/components/__test__/my-button.test.js:28:38)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 passed, 2 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
```

Comment: what happens if you don't use settimeout?

Comment: test fails expected 1 received 0

Comment: can you share the error you are getting if there's no "setTimeout" ?

Comment: I have updated it with failing test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using settimeout enforces this order for the test expectations.

`getUser` → `testExpectations`

With the present `MyButton` implementation, there isn't a straight forward way to achieve that. `getUser` needs to be extracted out and passed as a prop to `MyButton` so that there can be finer control on the promise chain *i.e.* chain test expectations on `getUser`

**Sample**

```
getUser().then(testExpectations)
```

In the first step of the refactor, call `getUser` in button `onClick` in place of the simulate call to the `ShallowWrapper` of your component.

This is what simulate does but it returns a wrapper instance. You don't want this; you want the promise returned from calling `getUser` so that you can chain to it.

```
it("must test the button click", (done) => {
  fetch.mockImplementation(() => {
    return Promise.resolve({
      status: 200,
      json: () => Promise.resolve({ name: "Manas", userId: 2 })
    });
  });

  const wrapper = shallow(<MyButton />);
  const button = wrapper.find("button");
  const onClick = button.prop('onClick');

  onClick().then(() => {
    wrapper.update();
    expect(wrapper.find("p").length).toBe(1);
    fetch.mockClear();
    done();
  })
})
```

The next step of the refactor will be to forward `getUser` as a property to `MyButton`. This may not be necessary if you find that `MyButton` will always use that specific implementation for its click event handler.

Comment: still i my test fails with same error expected 1 received 0

Comment: Hmm, let me investigate

Answer (score 0):

If you have async invocations during your test run, you have to run your assertions/expectation at the end of event loop.

```
it('must test the button click', done => {
  fetch.mockImplementation(() => {
    return Promise.resolve({
      status: 200,
      json: () => {
        return Promise.resolve({ name: 'Manas', userId: 2 });
      }
    });
  });
  const wrapper = shallow(<MyButton />);

  wrapper.find('button').simulate('click'); // async invocation

  // wait till async action is done
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setImmediate(() => {
      resolve();
    }, 0);
  }).then(() => {
    wrapper.update(); // you probably won't need this line
    expect(wrapper.find('p').length).toBe(1);
    fetch.mockClear();
    done();
  });
});
```

I usually have this written out as a util method in all my projects.

```
// test-helper.js
export const waitForAsyncActionsToFinish = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setImmediate(() => {
      resolve();
    }, 0);
  });
};

it('test something', (done) => {
  // mock some async actions
  const wrapper = shallow(<Component />);

  // componentDidMount async actions
  waitForAsyncActionsToFinish().then(() => {
    wrapper.find('.element').simulate('click');

    // onClick async actions - you have to wait again
    waitForAsyncActionsToFinish().then(() => {
      expect(wrapper.state.key).toEqual('val');
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: This requires that all async-parts of the code (are mocked to) resolve with a timeout equal to 0, in order to have the promise returned by `waitForAsyncActionsToFinish` resolved last. Having all async ops mocked and returning immediately may not be always suitable e.g. when the rendering includes animations and one needs a delay to check for results.

Comment: `setImmediate` adds a new async call at the end of the event loop. So basically we resolve after all async invocations are complete. But you are right that this might not work with timeouts. That's when we start using jest timers or sinon timers. OPs question is more focussed towards async actions without timeouts. This should solve the problem OP is facing.

Comment: Your answer i think bit hacky it just replaces setTimeout with setImmediate